# Cox Model - Are Censored Observations in the Risk Set?

Tags: survival, cox-model, ties

I'm running a cox proportional hazards model. I'm somewhat new to the area and have a question about the definition of the risk set and the use of it in computing partial likelihoods.

Specifically, when looking at the [derivation of the cox partial likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model#The_Cox_model) (also [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~mlunn/lecturenotes2.pdf)) censored observations are not included in the failure times. In addition if you look at [Efron's method for ties](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1977.10480613) (remark G in section 6) there's a product over elements in a risk set, but he looks at items that all *fail* at the same time.

My question, then, is probably quite simple: are censored observations included in risk sets?

That is if $t_1<t_2$ and I have some failures at $t_1$ and some censored observations that were censored at $t_2$, do I include those observations when I'm computing $\sum_{j\in R(t_1)}\theta_j$ or in the wikipedia notation $\sum_{i:Y_i\geq t_1}\theta_j$?

Comment: Short answer: yes. At time $t_1$, individuals _who so happen to be later censored_ are still at risk. One thing that may be confusing you is that we don't evaluate the likelihood at time $t$ if no one died at that time.

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon I think that's where I got a bit confused. If you look at derivations of the partial likelihood they often have a censoring term explicitly included so that the terms of the sum vanish for censored observations.

As a follow up, if we have mix of censored and uncensored patients at time $t$, then we evaluate the likelihood at time $t$, include both censored and uncensored in the risk set, but only those who actually had observed failures/deaths in the death set $D_j$ ?

Comment: Yea, that sounds correct